# Get filename/path of the document currently open in another program/window

Tags: windows, accessibility, document, ui-automation

I'm working on a program that acts as a Windows Accessibility / UI Automation API client, consuming accessibility data from other programs (much like a screen reader does). I'm looking for a way to get the full path of the current "document" (or other file) open in a program. So, for example, Word might give me the path to the current .docx file, Paint the path to the current image file, WMP the path to an audio or video file... you get the idea. Is there a way to do this?

On a Mac, I'd use [`NSAccessibilityDocumentAttribute`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityattributename/1530064-document), but Windows doesn't seem to have an equivalent accessibility property. A few other questions I looked at:

- [Getting the path & filename of the open document in any Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267877/getting-the-path-filename-of-the-open-document-in-any-windows-application) (last answer in 2009, may have been unaware of accessibility APIs, no answer gives reliably accurate data)
- [How to get filename and path of file opened in Notepad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166634/how-to-get-filename-and-path-of-file-opened-in-notepad) - five years old, specific to one program, only answer given is incomplete.

So... is there any equivalent to `NSAccessibilityDocumentAttribute`, and if not, is there a reasonable way to re-implement it (possibly doing stuff outside of the accessibility tree / API)? It's more important that this return correct information (i.e. never give me a file that *isn't* open in the relevant program/window) than that it be universally available.

I'm using C# (via [`System.Windows.Automation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx) for accessibility) but could use other languages if needed, so long as they'll run on Windows 10 (downlevel support nice but not mandatory).